# escape period (.) character in mod_rewrite regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have a .htaccess file set up with this rule:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user\.php?user=$1 [L]`

which works as expected:
**mysite.com/joe** becomes **mysite.com/user.php?user=joe**

How could I change the regex to include periods in a possible username?

For example I would like
**mysite.com/joe.bloggs** to go to **mysite.com/user=joe.bloggs**

Currently this brings up a 404 missing page error.

I have tried `^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)$ user\.php?user=$1 [L]`
But this produces an internal error 500 (I think this is due to an infinite loop: user.php is designed to redirect to the homepage if no user is specified.)

I'm pretty new to all of this (regex especially). Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try this RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._\-]+)$ user\.php?user=$1 [L]

Comment: This redirects everything to mysite.com/user.php?user=user.php including just mysite.com - Not sure why :S ?

Comment: It suddenly works now as
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+) test\.php?user=$1 [L]`
Can't quite explain it

Comment: you were scaping it before, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if the requested URLs is not a file or folder. This will prevent the redirect loop for URLs like `/user.php`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Strangely, this RegEx didn't work for me until I put the dot from end to front like [.a-zA-Z0-9_-] Thank you.

Comment: @kubilay the dash defines a range, it needs to be escaped in there like this: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)$ user.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]` but since you moved it to the end it removes the error, technically you need to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

`.` has no special meaning inside a character class, so there is no need to escape it.

If that doesn't help, try putting `die("Test")` right at the start of `user.php`. This will allow you to see if the error is coming from the rewrite, or the PHP file.

Comment: If I simply add the . to the regex, then it does work but even mysite.com redirects to mysite.com/test.php?user=test.php
The die('Test'); did prevent the loop though! Thanks

Comment: This is correct, for more info see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes